An integral equation over two CDFs on the unit interval
I have $F_1,F_2$ two CDFs of random variables over $[0,1]$ and a number $0 < m < 1$. I'd like to somehow characterize the solutions to the constraint:
$$
\forall x, 0 < x < 1: m(1 -x) - m\int_x^1 F_1 \left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right) \text{d}s  - (1 - m) \int_0^x F_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)\text{d}s = 0
$$
It seems that choosing $F_1$ should completely determine $F_2$, but beyond that I have trouble saying anything specific about the solutions. Ideally, I'd like to express $F_1$ in terms of $F_2$, but any other useful characterization would help.
I am interested in the general $m$, but if that helps, the special case of $m = \frac{1}{2}$ would address most of my problems.
Thanks for any hints, including comments that I shouldn't expect there to be a "nice" solution.
EDIT: I cannot make any further assumptions about the random variables represented by $F_1,F_2$. Notably, the variables may be discrete (or a mix of continous and discrete) and thus $F_1,F_2$ may not be differentiable. A solution requiring the existence of a PDF is still of some interest, but not fully useful.

I've edited my answer and found a nice result, which is hopefully correct. It would be great, if you can share feedback whether the result works or not.

@user408858 Ah, yes thats true. I misread it. But its still not clear to me if you pick a random CDF $F_1$ that the $F_2$ you find will be a CDF.

@Winther: I kept staring at the $F_1$ I found under the assumption that $F_2$ is a CDF. I'm not sure, if this is true. Maybe it is more easy to see from the PDF, i.e. the $f_1$ I found?

@user408858 If your result is correct then it does confirms this suspicion that we cannot freely choose one CDF and hope to get a CDF as a solution here. For example in your example you let $f_2 = 1$ ($F_2 = x$) be uniform on $[0,1]$ then $f_1 = (1-x)/x$ is not a PDF on $[0,1]$.

@Winther: However, if I plugin $F_2(x)=x$, I find $F_1(x)=2-x+\log(x)$, which certainly satisfies $F_1(1)=1$ and is increasing on $[0,1]$. Though of course, one needs to consider $F_1(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[\delta,1]}(x)(2-x+\log(x))$ where $\delta$ solves the equation $x=e^{x-2}$. Then, it should turn into a PDF? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%281-x%29%2Fx+from+-ProductLog%28-1%2Fe%5E2%29+to+1 But still something is odd here...

First note, that
$$m(1 -x) - m\int_x^1 F_1 \left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right) \text{d}s  - (1 - m) \int_0^x F_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)\text{d}s = 0$$
is equivalent to
$$\int_x^1\left(1-F_1\left( \frac{s-x}{s}\right)\right)ds=\frac{1-m}{m}\int_0^xF_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)ds$$
Using integration by substitution, i.e.
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}H(s)ds=\int_a^bH(g(s))g'(s)ds,$$
with $g(s)=\frac{x}{1-s}$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_x^1\left(1-F_1\left( \frac{s-x}{s}\right)\right)ds
%&=\int_{g(0)}^{g(1-x)}\left(1-F_1\left( \frac{s-x}{s}\right)\right)ds\\
%&=\int_{0}^{1-x}\left(1-F_1\left( \frac{g(s)-x}{g(s)}\right)\right)g'(s)ds\\
&=\int_0^{1-x}\left( 1-F_1(s) \right)\frac{x}{(1-s)^2}ds\\
&=x\int_0^{1-x}\left( 1-F_1(s) \right)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Again, integration by substitution with $g(s)=1-\frac{1-x}{s}$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^xF_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)ds
&=\int_{1-x}^1F_2\left(s\right)\frac{1-x}{s^2}ds\\
&=(1-x)\int_{1-x}^1F_2\left(s\right)\frac{1}{s^2}ds\\
&=(1-x)\int_{0}^xF_2(1-s)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^{1-x}\left( 1-F_1(s) \right)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds=\frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1-x}{x}\int_0^xF_2\left(1-s\right)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds$$
Differentiation with respect to $x$ results in
$$\left(F_1(1-x)-1\right)\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}F_2(1-x)\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^xF_2(1-s)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds\right)$$
and
$$F_1(1-x)=1+\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}F_2(1-x)-\int_0^xF_2(1-s)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds\right)$$
Consequently,
$$F_1(x)=F_1(1-(1-x))=1+\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}F_2(x)-\int_0^{1-x}F_2(1-s)\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}ds\right)$$
Another differentiation with respect to $x$ results in
$$f_1(x)=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}f_2(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}F_2(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}F_2(x)\right)=\frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1-x}{x}f_2(x)$$
Some considerations: Choosing the most trivial example, $m=\frac{1}{2}$ and $F_2\sim U[0,1]$ the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, shows that $F_1$ cannot be a distribution. It holds $f_2(x)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$, which produces the contradiction
$$\int_0^1f_1(s)ds=\int_0^1\frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1-s}{s}f_2(s)ds=\int_0^1\frac{1-s}{s}ds=\infty$$
This does not change for any other $0<m<1$. This means, that there has to be a $0<\delta<1$, such that $\operatorname{supp}(f_2)\subset (\delta,1]$, if $f_2$ is the PDF of a uniform distribution. Only if this is true, you can find
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1-s}{s}f_2(s)ds=1$$
Let's pick  $F_2\sim U[0.5,1]$. Then it holds $f_2(x)=2\mathbb{1}_{[0.5,1]}(x)$ and you find
$$
\begin{aligned}
1=\int_0^1\frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1-s}{s}f_2(s)ds
&=2\frac{1-m}{m}\int_{0.5}^1\frac{1-s}{s}ds\\
&=2\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\log(s)-s\right)\big|_{s=0.5}^{s=1}\\
&=2\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\log(0.5)+0.5\right)
\end{aligned}$$
for $m=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2(\log(0.5)+0.5)}}$ leading to the PDF
$$f_1(x)= 2\left(1-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2(\log(0.5)+0.5)}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2(\log(0.5)+0.5)}} \right)^{-1} \frac{1-x}{x} \mathbb{1}_{[0.5,1]}(x)$$
If you, the other way around, choose a fixed $0<m<1$, it should not be too hard to construct a $f_2$, such that
$$\int_0^1f_1(s)ds=1$$
However, the special cases where $m$ tends to $0$ or $1$ need most likely some attention.

This is very good! I was able to follow and verify all of the steps and learn a bit along the way. A did check with some stuff I assume should be a solution and it works. I am primarily interested in the CDF results, so non-existence of PDFs doesn't worry me. Also it is not unexpected that some choices of one of the CDFs will never give a CDF as a result.

It also looks like the nice solution for PDFs might generalize to non-differentiable CDFs in the sense that the for all point masses you need $P(X_1 = x) = \frac{1-m}{m}\frac{1-x}{x}P(X_2 = x)$...

This is good news! Yes, I was hoping, that you might be able to replace the integral with sums and find a way to use it in the discrete case. In what scenario did you encounter the "constraint" you are describing? Maybe there is the chance to do a bit more on this? Would you mind, if I reach out via email?

Feel free to reach out. The context is validating Bayesian computation. In some ways I now realize a result like this is expected, because the specific problem is closely related (or maybe even equivalent to) calibration of binary predictions, but I arrived there from a quite different place, so it only became obvious through some of the results obtained. OTOH there are generalizations which should not be equivalent and hopefully similar tricks could lead to a solution there...

Completely discounting the restraints placed on $x$ and $m$, one may approach the above equation analytically:
\begin{align}
m(1-x)-m\int_x^1F_1\left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s-(1-m)\int_0^xF_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)\mathrm{d}s&=0\\
m\left[s\right|_x^1-m\int_x^1F_1\left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s&=(1-m)\int_0^xF_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\\
m\int_x^1\mathrm{d}s-m\int_x^1F_1\left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s&=(1-m)\int_0^xF_2\left(\frac{1-x}{1-s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\\
m\int_x^1\left(1-F_1\left(\frac{s-x}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s&=(1-m)\int_0^xF_2\left(\frac{x-1}{s-1}\right)\mathrm{d}s\\
m\int_x^1\left(1-F_1\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s&=(1-m)\int_1^{x+1}F_2\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\\
\int_x^1\left(1-F_1\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s&=\frac{m-1}{m}\int_{x+1}^1F_2\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\\
\end{align}
Assume that both sides of the equation are differentiable with respect to $x$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\int_x^1\left(1-F_1\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s\right)&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\int_{x+1}^1F_2\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\right)\\
F_1(0)-1+\int_x^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(1-F_1\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\int_{x+1}^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(F_2\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s-F_2\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)\\
F_1(0)-1+\int_x^1\frac{1}{s}F_1'\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\int_{x+1}^1\frac{1}{s}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s-F_2\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\right)\\
\end{align}
Once again, assume both sides of the equation are differentiable with respect to $x$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(F_1(0)-1+\int_x^1\frac{1}{s}F_1'\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s\right)&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\int_{x+1}^1\frac{1}{s}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s-F_2\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)\right)\right)\\
-\frac{F_1'(0)}{x}+\int_x^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{s}F_1'\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\int_{x+1}^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{s}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{x+1}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{2F_2'\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)\\
-\frac{F_1'(0)}{x}-\int_x^1\frac{1}{s^2}F_1''\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\int_{x+1}^1\frac{1}{s^2}F_2''\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{x+1}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{2F_2'\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)\\
-\frac{F_1'(0)}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\int_x^1\frac{x}{s^2}F_1''\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\int_{x+1}^1\frac{1-x}{s^2}F_2''\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{x+1}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{2F_2'\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)\\
-\frac{F_1'(0)}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\left[F_1'\left(1-\frac{x}{s}\right)\right|_x^1&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\left[F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{s}\right)\right|_{x+1}^1-\frac{1}{x+1}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{2F_2'\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)\\
-\frac{F_1'(0)}{x}-\frac{1}{x}\left(F_1'\left(1-x\right)-F_1'\left(0\right)\right)&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\left(F_2'\left(x-1\right)-F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{x+1}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-\frac{2F_2'\left(1-\frac{2}{x+1}\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)\\
\frac{F_1'\left(0\right)-F_1'\left(1-x\right)-F_1'(0)}{x}&=\frac{m-1}{m}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\left(F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-F_2'\left(x-1\right)\right)-\frac{x+3}{\left(x+1\right)^2}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)\\
\frac{F_1'\left(1-x\right)}{x}&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)+\frac{1}{1-x}F_2'\left(x-1\right)-\frac{x+3}{\left(x+1\right)^2}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)\right)\\
\frac{F_1'\left(1-x\right)}{x}&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{\left(x+1\right)^2-(x-1)(x+3)}{(x-1)\left(x+1\right)^2}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)+\frac{1}{1-x}F_2'\left(x-1\right)\right)\\
F_1'(1-x)&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{4x}{(x-1)\left(x+1\right)^2}F_2'\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)+\frac{x}{1-x}F_2'(x-1)\right)\\
F_1'(x)&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\frac{4(x-1)}{x\left(x-2\right)^2}F_2'\left(\frac{x}{x-2}\right)+\frac{1-x}{x}F_2'(-x)\right)\\
\int F_1'(x)\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{1-m}{m}\int\left(\frac{4(x-1)}{x\left(x-2\right)^2}F_2'\left(\frac{x}{x-2}\right)+\frac{1-x}{x}F_2'(-x)\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
F_1(x)+C&\overset{u\leftarrow\frac{x}{x-2}}{=}\frac{1-m}{m}\left(-\int\frac{u+1}{u^2}F_2'(u)\mathrm{d}u+\int\frac{1-x}{x}F_2'(-x)\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
F_1(x)+C&\overset{v\leftarrow-x}{=}\frac{1-m}{m}\left(-\int\frac{u+1}{u^2}F_2'(u)\mathrm{d}u+\int\frac{1+v}{v}F_2'(v)\mathrm{d}v\right)\\
F_1(x)+C&\overset{x\leftarrow u}{=}\frac{1-m}{m}\left(-\int\frac{x+1}{x^2}F_2'(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int\frac{1+v}{v}F_2'(v)\mathrm{d}v\right)\\
F_1(x)+C&\overset{x\leftarrow v}{=}\frac{1-m}{m}\left(-\int\frac{x+1}{x^2}F_2'(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int\frac{1+x}{x}F_2'(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
F_1(x)+C&=\frac{1-m}{m}\int\frac{x+x^2-x-1}{x^2}F_2'(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
F_1(x)+C&=\frac{1-m}{m}\int\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}F_2'(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
F_1(x)+C&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(\int F_2'(x)\mathrm{d}x-\int\frac{F_2'(x)}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
F_1(x)&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(F_2(x)+C-\int\frac{F_2'(x)}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
F_1(x)&=\frac{1-m}{m}\left(F_2(x)-\frac{F_2(x)}{x^2}+C-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{F_2(x)}{x^3}\mathrm{d}x\right)
\end{align}
Though the above certainly looks nicer than the original equation, note that it makes heavy use of assumptions, namely that $F_1,F_2\in C^2[0,1]$. Though it may reasonably be assumed that both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are differentiable on the interval $x\in(0,1)$ (given they are both CDFs, thereby implying the existence of their first derivatives as PDFs), the condition that $F_1''$ and $F_2''$ or $f_1'$ and $f_2'$, respectively, exist places certain restrictions on the solutions to the original formulation of the problem. This isn't even taking into consideration the bounds on $x$ and $m$, nor the values of $x$ for which the equations or the integrals within them appear to be undefined. However, I do hope this helps you in some way.
Edit: Simplified further.

I probably should have been explicit about this in the question: unfortunately, the CDFs cannot be assumed to be continuous as they may be CDFs of discrete random variables. The continous case is also of interest, so I'll try to dig through this to see if the result allows me to move forward a bit.

That's quite alright; the problem was fun to solve and was great practice otherwise. My first instinct regarding characterization of the solutions would be to use something  involving convolutions or integral transforms (e.g. the Laplace or Fourier transforms), as those can be helpful in probability theory. Alternatively, assuming that a discrete random variable has a piecewise PDF constituted by numerous step functions, one could just formulate the derivatives of said PDF at certain values as being Dirac $\delta$ distributions in themselves.
